# How can I match two files based on different columns using awk?

Tags: awk

I need to match two files for each lines based on $5 and $6 from file 1, and $1 &$2 of file two and to print $3 of  file2 in file 1 when it matches.

File 1

```
7   81  1   47  13412   2013-09-27      18:39:34    
7   82  2   10  27723   2010-08-20      18:46:10        
7   83  1   67  27030   2010-05-23      18:51:54        
7   84  2   17  13412   2013-09-28      18:54:19
```

File 2

```
13412   2013-09-27   565  
27723   2010-08-20   582.333  
27030   2010-05-23   514  
13412   2013-09-28   565  
27723   2010-08-21   591.25  
27030   2010-05-24   527  
13412   2013-09-29   561.5
```

I have tried the following code but it just print the first file without matching

```
awk ‘NR==FNR {a[$1,$2] = $3; next}   $0 = $0 FS a[$1,$2]’ file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk one-liner may give you a hand:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2]=$3;next}
    {k=$5 FS $6}$0 = $0 ((k in a)? FS a[k]:"")' f2 f1
```

With given inputs, it outputs:

```
7 81 1 47 13412 2013-09-27 18:39:34 565
7 82 2 10 27723 2010-08-20 18:46:10 582.333
7 83 1 67 27030 2010-05-23 18:51:54 514
7 84 2 17 13412 2013-09-28 18:54:19 565
```

#### Your problem

- You can use `$x,$y` to indicate a *key*, but when you processed file1, you should use `$5,$6` instead of `$1,$2`
- If the corresponding entry was not found in file2, you will anyway concatenate a `FS` in output. I don't know if it is desired.

**Short explanation from @Olivier Dulac (comment below):**

> {k=...} (defition of k, occuring on each line of f1) on a separate
>   line from the $0 = ... (redefinition of $0 by including at its end the
>   value of a[k], if it exists) part, that is a "alwayus true" condition
>   that then prints the new $0.

Comment: beaten again :)

Comment: @Inian I just opened the SO homepage, and seen this Q... :-)

Comment: You should edit the "one-liner" to have the `{k=...}` (defition of k, occuring on each line of f1) on a separate line from the `$0 = ...` (redefinition of `$0` by including at its end the value of a[k], if it exists) part, that is a "always true" condition that then prints the new $0. It will be a bit clearer that way ^^ . But this is not codegolf ;)  you may want to add some clarity by not relying too much on default actions

Comment: @OlivierDulac regarding the default action. I noticed that OP has used in this way, so , just followed. your comment makes sense.

Comment: @Kent: indeed, but I prefer to be (much more ^^) verbose in my script samples, in case the other persons reading an answer are not aware of the subtleties involved...